# Rails + Devise: How to catch the event of logging out a user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am logging users' activities and when a user logged out, I want to call a method. How do I do that?

In routes, I have the following:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get 'logout',                             to: 'devise/sessions#destroy'
end
```

Do I need to create for this purpose a SessionController or is there other way around?

Answer (score 1):

You don't really "catch the event" as Rails is a MVC framework and not event oriented.

Instead you subclass the controller and call `super` with a block to "tap-into" the original implementation:

```
devise_scope :user, controllers: {
  sessions: 'my_sessions'
}
```

```
class MySessionController < ApplicationController
  def destroy
    super do
      # do your thing
      # this block is called after the user is signed out 
      # but before the response is set. 
    end
  end
end
```

This works since [the Devise controllers yield](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/5d5636f03ac19e8188d99c044d4b5e90124313af/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L30).